# Short story (+radio play?) in which astronauts outside their ship slowly drift apart in space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, astronauts, radio-play

Looking for a short story in which the crew of a spaceship for some reason find themselves outside the ship, drifting apart in outer space. They can communicate via their radios but are individually drifting apart.

One by one, they lose communication as they drift further away from each other.

Might have also been adapted into a radio play?

Comment: I can't remember the title, but Ray Bradbury wrote one like this.  I think one of the men ended up drifting into a cluster of asteroids that orbited the Sun every so many thousands of years and he knew he'd be part of that.  This was also used as the ending of John Carpenter's movie _Dark Star_.

Comment: Do you remember anything else? Where did they come from? Where did they end up? Did any survive? When and where did you read the story?

Comment: It's definitely the Bradbury story.

Comment: @OrganicMarble unless I'm missing something the dupe-target is not accepted, though? (See also [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41293/watching-gravity-reminded-me-of-a-short-story-i-read-in-the-60s-but-cant-pla#comment391593_41293))

Comment: @Jenayah You are right. Somebody else had used it in a duplicate closure, and I didn't check. Thanks.

Comment: Namely: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138351/short-story-about-spacesuited-astronauts-hurled-into-space-after-ship-explodes/138481#138481

Comment: @OrganicMarble well I guess that one should be reopened as well, then. Care to speed up the process and hammer it? :P

Answer (score 23):

["Kaleidoscope"](https://www.scaryforkids.com/kaleidoscope-by-ray-bradbury/) (1949) in Ray Bradbury's *The Illustrated Man*.

From [BookRags](http://www.bookrags.com/studyguide-the-illustrated-man/chapanal003.html#gsc.tab=0):

> The crew of a rocket ship are ejected into space after an explosion and begin to drift away from each other. Stone says he's headed for the moon, Hollis floats toward Earth and will burn up in the atmosphere. Stimson can't control his fear, and Hollis tries to calm him down, with Applegate joining the conversation. Hollis is overcome with helpless anger.

And the radio play was Episode 48 (Sept. 15, 1951) of [*Dimension X*](https://archive.org/details/OTRR_Dimension_X_Singles/Dimension_X_1951-09-15__48_TheKaleidoscope.mp3).

Ray Bradbury also hosted a fantastic modern radio adaptation of "Kaleidoscope".  It played frequently on NPR stations in the 1980's as part of a series called [*Bradbury 13*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv7mi12vHMo).  Stereo, great sound effects, music.  All thirteen episodes of the series are worth a listen.

Comment: That's the one I remember.  Don't know if it's what the questioner was looking for, though.

Comment: Kaleidoscope it is!! Thank you so much.

Comment: @trigby: instead of writing a thanking comment, you should mark this as the accepted answer, because (1) it rewards the answerer, (2) it helps readers in the future to quicly find the correct answer (3) if your accept ratio is too small, people might be less willing to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: Nice link, Kyle - I'd forgotten about that site. Thanks!

Comment: @user14111 - No, I don't mind at all; I had no idea there was a radio play. Completes the answer nicely, thanks!

Comment: I remember this one! Cool story.